# Trying to read value from .env file throws undefined error in playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I am unable to get the url value from the `.env` file in my `playwright` test, while running the test, it is throwing error baseURL of undefined,could someone please advise on the issue ?
TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseURL' of undefined

```
  10 | test('Access the Playwright Page', async ({ page }) => {
  11 |   const playwrightDev = new PlaywrightDevPage(page);
> 12 |   await playwrightDev.goto(Config.baseURL);
     |                                   ^
```

Following is my `.env` file.

```
URL=https://playwright.dev/
```

Below is my `playwright.config.js` file and settings

```
const { devices } = require('@playwright/test');

/** @type {import('@playwright/test').PlaywrightTestConfig} */

const config = {
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  use: {
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
    baseURL: process.env.URL,
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    },
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Below is my `example.spec.js` file

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
const { PlaywrightDevPage } = require('./playwright-dev-page');
const { Config } = require('../playwright.config');

test('Access the Playwright Page', async ({ page }) => {
  const playwrightDev = new PlaywrightDevPage(page);
  await playwrightDev.goto(Config.baseURl);
 
});
```

Comment: `Config` is undefined because `playwright.config.js` doesn't export an object with the property name `Config` ... if you `const Config  = require('../playwright.config');` then it's be `Config.use.baseURL` that you want
`

Comment: Now getting `page.goto: url: expected string, got undefined`

Comment: what is the content of `Config` in that case (a console.log should help you determine what you are dealing with)

Comment: ``
const { devices } = require('@playwright/test');

/** @type {import('@playwright/test').PlaywrightTestConfig} */

const config = {
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  use: {
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
    baseURL: process.env.URL,
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    },
  ],
};

module.exports = config;``

Comment: I have added my `playwright.config.js ` content in my question. Could you please have a look.

Comment: Tried `console.log("Details here:"+config.use.trace);` is printing value...but console.log("Details here:"+config.use.baseURL);  showing console.log("Details here:"+config.use.trace);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load `dotenv` inside your config via: `require('dotenv').config()`

Then you can inside your tests use the env vars of your "dotenv files" via e.g.: `process.env.FOOBAR`

See here for dotenv usage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: This is really strange as example config on their side doesn't mention requirement on dotenv. https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#basic-configuration

Comment: It gets mentioned here: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parameterize#env-files

Answer (score 3):

```
step 1 : npm install dotenv --save
step 2 : Create an .env file in root of the project
step 3 : Add env veriable like this
    BASE_URL = 'https://example.net'
    USERNAME = 'username'
    PASSWORD = 'password'
step 4 : go to playwrigth.config.ts file and add the following block
    import dotenv from 'dotenv'
    dotenv.config();
step 5 : 
    const baseUrl = process.env.BASE_URL as string;
    const userName = process.env.USERNAME as string;
    const password = process.env.PASSWORD as string;
step 6 : use this in your code. Happy coding :)
```